# Error while clearing values of a dropdown menu in dash, using a clear button

Tags: python, html, css, web-applications, plotly-dash

I am trying to provide an option to the user to clear the values entered in the dropdown through a clear button but upon running the app, I am receiving the following error (due to which I am not able to select an option in the dropdown):

> > Cannot read property 'length' of null

This is my code for the clear button:

```
html.Button('Clear', id = 'clear', n_clicks = 0, style={'color' : '#FFFFFF', 'fontSize' : '12px', 'width': '150px'})
```

And this is my code for the clearing function:

```
@app.callback(  
    Output('Month', 'options'),
    [Input('clear', 'n_clicks')]
)
def clearDropDown1(n_clicks):
        if n_clicks: 
            return None
```

Comment: Can you also share the code for the dropdown?

Comment: '''html.Label('Select Month', style={'color' : '#FFFFFF', 'fontSize': '16px'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='Month',
            options = [
                {'label' : 'January', 'value' : 1},
                {'label' : 'February', 'value' : 2},
                {'label' : 'March', 'value' : 3},
],
            placeholder = 'Choose a month'
        ),'''

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've run it locally, and the problem is being caused by the callback. It's updating the `options` prop to be `None`, and the the app can't read the property `length` of that (`null` in JS).

Your callback could take a form like this (worked for me):

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('Month', 'options'),
    [Input('clear', 'n_clicks')]
)
def clearDropDown1(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        return []
    return [{'label': 'January', 'value': 1}, {'label': 'February', 'value': 2},
                          {'label': 'March', 'value': 3}, ]
```

The trouble is, when you click the button, the callback will not have any options in it anymore. Did you know that there is a `clearable` prop which allows users to X out the selection they've made?

edit:

In response to your comment, you will need a multi-output callback. It will take this form:

```py
@app.callback(
    [
        Output('Month', 'options'),
        Output('Year', 'options'),
        ...
    ],
    [Input('clear', 'n_clicks')]
)
def clearDropDown1(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:
        return [], [], ...
    return [{'label': 'January', 'value': 1}, {'label': 'February', 'value': 2},
                          {'label': 'March', 'value': 3}, ],
        [{'label': 2020, 'value': 2020}, {'label': 2019, 'value': 2019}], ...
```

The function must return a value for each `Output` in the decorator. I would say you probably need to update the `value` prop instead of options if you want to have it work like the clear button for all of them together.

Comment: Yeah I got the same problem. 
So the clearable property is set to True by default and the user can X out the selection but i have multiple dropdowns and i want to make a clear button that clears all the selections of all dropdowns just by clicking that button